# spark_apply Cannot run program “Rscript”: in directory "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\spark\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7\tmp\local\spark-..\userFiles

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

Following first instructions of the book "Mastering Apache Spark with R"
about spark_apply, on a local cluster under windows and using RGui,
launching :

```
install.packages("sparklyr")
install.packages("pkgconfig")
spark_install("2.3")
Installing Spark 2.3.3 for Hadoop 2.7 or later.
spark_installed_versions()
library(dplyr,sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.3.3")
cars <- copy_to(sc, mtcars)    
cars %>% spark_apply(~round(.x))
```

is returning the following error:

```
spark_apply Cannot run program “Rscript”:  in directory "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\spark\spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7\tmp\local\spark-..\userFiles-..  
CreateProcess error=2, The file specified can't be found
```

How to corectly install sparklyr and
how to get ride of this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spark node needs the Rscript executable in its path. For the master node, it is [possible to set the path to the Rscript executable](https://spark.rstudio.com/guides/distributed-r/#configuration) using the following commands:

```
config <- spark_config()
config[["spark.r.command"]] <- "d:/path/to/R-3.4.2/bin/Rscript.exe"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)
```

Let find [here](https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-distribute-your-r-code-with-sparklyr-and-cloudera-data-science-workbench/) more explanations and guidelines for distributed environments.